# Forward Traffic from Windows EC2 Instance to ElasticSearch VPC Endpoint

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, ssh-tunnel, aws-vpc, aws-elasticsearch

I have Windows EC2 instance I use for my public-facing C# API. The VPC(and related Internet Gateway, subnets, etc) are all default.

I've now setup an AWS ElasticSearch service using their more secure VPC Endpoint option (instead of public-facing) and I've associated it to the same subnet and vpc as my above Windows EC2 instance.

I'd like to get them to talk to each other.

Reading from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html

It seems what you'd do is ssh tunnel / port forward traffic from localhost:9200 on the EC2 instance to the actual Elastic Search service (via that VPC endpoint).

It seems this command is where the magic happens:
ssh -i ~/.ssh/your-key.pem ec2-user@your-ec2-instance-public-ip -N -L 9200:vpc-your-amazon-es-domain.region.es.amazonaws.com:443

but that is for a Linux EC2 instance.

If I am Remote Desktopped into my Windows EC2 instance (the API), how can I make it so when I go to a browser, http://localhost:9200
 will send traffic to my VPC Endpoint:

vpc-your-amazon-es-domain.region.es.amazonaws.com:443

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I'll answer my two questions:

First, it's actually quite easy, just RDP to your box and access the instance directly via the VPC endpoint. You don't need to do anything wacky like port forwarding using the netsh command or anything like that. Simply make sure the server (in my case my API) is on the same VPC and you're fine. I just had an error in my connection string that's why it didn't connect. To confirm, I RDP'D in and was able to hit the endpoint directly in a browser on port 80. While it's true the actual Elasticsearch runs on port 9200, you don't need to forward to localhost:9200 --> vpc:9200.

Now, regarding the second question, about hitting it locally, I think the problem is that because this service lacks a public IP address and you can't access it, that you can go through some complicated setup on AWS, or easier is just set it up to run locally for now until you are ready to use the VPC one (and thus your code will just run).  Another option is to use security groups and make a publicly accessible cluster for now, and then when your code is done, search service/layer done, etc, you can start anew with a VPC/secure Elasticsearch service and that should be it.

Another thing that many mention is that it is cheaper/you have more control of things if you setup your own Elasticsearch on your local machine, and then set one up on EC2 (this is just reading blogs and seeing people mention how much frustration they had with it).